# Play! framework immediate save?

Tags: jpa, playframework

In Play! if you call this:

```
void method()
{
User u = User();
u.name = "bob";
u.save();
while(true){/* endless loop */}
}
```

Nothing will actually be saved into the db (The Play! class needs to get the hand back to flush the saves.)

How do I have to proceed in order to either force a flush or to make it automatically flush at save ?

Comment: Could you tell us your usecase? Because most of the time this is a bad idea.

Comment: Actually I never call while(true){}; but as I did a very large import within the method, that last one gave back the hand very lately (which resulted in no db changes all that time long). Writing the question that way was much shorter and the expected answer was the same.

Comment: Sounds like you better trigger some job and use ajax to give feedback to the user.

Comment: Exactly, actually it is in a job already. I then run importer.now(); to startup the process. The import takes few hours… I only need to do this once a month and to look at the logs if everything was fine or not.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The reason why your changes are not visible in the database, is that the transaction is not yet commited and so other transactions can't **see** your changes (at least in a good database like PostgreSQL, Oracle, MSSQL, DB2).
To make your changes seen, you'll have to commit your transaction before it enters the infinite loop, like this:

```
void method()
{
    User u = User();
    u.name = "bob";
    u.save();
    JPA.em().flush();
    JPA.em().getTransaction().commit();

    while(true){/* endless loop */}

}
```

If you want to access your database inside the infinite loop or after it (if you have a break condition), you'll have to **begin** a new transaction or you'll get exceptions from hibernate. Do this like this

```
void method()
{
    User u = User();
    u.name = "bob";
    u.save();
    JPA.em().flush();
    JPA.em().getTransaction().commit();

    while(true){
      // do some stuff

      /* TRANSACTIONAL BLOCK BEGINS */
      JPA.em().getTransaction().begin();
      try{
          // do some stuff
          // fetching, updating, deleting, whatever

          JPA.em().getTransaction().commit();
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
          // if an error occurs, rollback the transaction
          JPA.em().getTransaction().rollback();
      }
      /* TRANSACTIONAL BLOCK ENDS */
      // do some other stuff
    }
   // copy the TRANSACTIONAL BLOCK from above, if you want to do stuff after the "infinite loop" as well.
}
```

It's important that you either **commit** or **rollback** the transaction in the loop, if you start it there, as else you'll run into problems with too many open transactions soon.

Comment: Yes, except for the infinite loop. Also, I believe that the 2 answers there were already clear enough. I don't thing it was needed for you to re-summarize them (badly) in a different answer

Comment: Thanks for your comment - I've enhanced the answer.

Answer (score 5):

As already said by Andrei Bodnarescu, you can use `JPA.em().flush()` or `User.em().flush()` to flush persistence context explicitly.

Note, however, that doing so won't make the saved entity immediately available to other transactions, since the current transaction should be committed first. You can commit the current transaction as `JPA.em().getTransaction().commit()`.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
User.em().flush();
```

If I'm not mistaken, the default Play! model holds a refference to the EntityManager which can be accessed like that.