# Play! framework 1.2.4 - immediate save from morphia

Tags: mongodb, selenium, playframework, morphia, playframework-1.x

I wrote selenium test that is run-time changes in the properties of an object mongodb (using the save method of the  morphia) and then checks whether this property is changed. But the outcome variables is not happening. How to make an immediate saving?

```
%{
    // load models
    // deleted = true
}%

#{selenium}            
    click('link=Delete')
    <!--                 
    SomeClass someObj = SomeClass.findById(id);
    someObj.deleted = true;
    someObj.save();
    -->
#{/selenium}

%{
    models.SomeClass someObj2 = models.SomeClass.find("fieldName", "fieldValue").get();
    boolean expectedStatus = someObj2.deleted;
    org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(expectedStatus);
}%
```

Save method doesnt change value in MongoDB during the test. Save work after the end of the test. This is a problem

Comment: i'm using 1.2.4 vervion of Play ! Framework

Comment: hey! don't think i understand your question, what is the expected result and what is the result you're getting?

Comment: Ok. I have the same problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8488565/play-framework-immediate-save But i dont use JPA. Im using Morphia plugin for play framework. There is no transaction in MongoDB.

Comment: i don't know the internals of this, but is it possible that the two blocks ```#{selenium}``` and ```%{..}%``` arent' executed in order? i would suppose that the groovy code gets run when the selenium test is generated (first) and only after that the actual selenium test would be run. (you can check by simply adding Logger.info() to the groovy code and some kind of alert to the selenium code)

Comment: no. they are executed in order. I checked.

Answer (score 0):

Use `WriteConcern` here. When doing an write operation(delete in your case), you can specify a "write concern" to tell the system that you want the write to only be considered complete when the data has (for example) been flushed to disk and replicated to X slaves.
Here an example for Morphia:

```
morpiaDao.delete(company, new WriteConcern(true));
```